# Mate Desktop - display sleep moves windows with dual monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, mate

I'm running Ubuntu MATE 20.04 with matching dual monitors. I want the computer to put the displays to sleep which it does, however when waking the displays and unlocking, all the windows have been moved to the primary screen, meaning i need to  move them back any time the screen locks.

Any idea of a fix or workaround?

Comment: You can ask the same question on http://ubuntu-mate.community/ for more productive answer.